# Oracle function issue PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: oracle, function, pivot

I am running snippet from [SQL Pivoting Antons Thunder](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/). 
I've bumped into a problem where the last function has a problem.

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:. @ ;
>   The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

The function looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION pivotex(p_stmt IN VARCHAR2, p_fmt IN VARCHAR2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy IN NUMBER := 0)
RETURN anydataset PIPELINED USING PivotImpl;
```

What am I missing here?

Download resource [AntonsPivoting.zip](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/images/antonsPivoting.zip)

Comment: How exactly are you running the pivotFun.sql script - which client and which command(s)? And which version of Oracle are you creating it in? I notice you've changed the function name, have you made any other changes? Did you keep the final `/` on the last line (on its own)?

Comment: I just changed the function name. I'm using oracle 12g. I ran the script directly from database console using DBVis.

Comment: I haven't used that; [maybe this helps though](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG91/Executing+Complex+Statements)? There also seems to be a separate dialog to create procedures. Did it create the type and body successfully? Did you need to set the slash delimiter, and did you keep the final one after the `create function`?

Comment: Yes i keep the slash at the end of the statement.  Both type and body created successfully.  Only the last function statement was error. Will have look at the link you gave.